# Java util.numberFormatException for input string: "2014-01-12 05-44-56"

Tags: java

I'm new in OFBiz, and Java. I used bellow block of code for checking date time input and use that for searching in table.

```
Timestamp strtDate = UtilDateTime.getTimestamp((String)request.getParameter("strt_date"));
if(strtDate != null)
{
     // then here i used the date for taking data.
}
```

When i fill the date time field of form to search or when no date is selected for searching error occure that show `numberFormatException`, so how i can solve that? thanks for any help and guide.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Apache ofbiz API](http://ci.apache.org/projects/ofbiz/site/javadocs/org/ofbiz/base/util/UtilDateTime.html#getTimestamp(java.lang.String)) it looks like `UtilDateTime#getTimestamp(String)` expects milliseconds value. You are passing in `"2014-01-12 05-44-56"`. You need to parse your date first. With pure pre 1.8 java (keep in mind that formatters aren't thread safe):

```
String dateString = "2014-01-12 05-44-56";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
UtilDateTime.getTimestamp(date.getTime());
```

Since java 1.8 (**highly** recommended to switch if you can!):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
long millis = date.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: I should calculate the date time as milliseconds first? then i should use that.

Comment: You could also provide a string with milliseconds as input too. However if you are provided with date in the format you have specified in your post, then yes, you do need to convert. Do not forget to consider timezones if this is important in your project :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass time in milliseconds not as you are passing.

you can check code also :

```
public static Timestamp getTimestamp(String milliSecs) throws NumberFormatException {
    return new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(milliSecs));
}
```

it will parse the data in long which you are passing and that should be valid long value.

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameter("strt_date")` will anyways return `String`, so no need to cast it explicitly to `String`. Moreover, there will be a contract between `Client` & `Server` on the required Date Format. So you have to parse the String-Date in the same format using `SimpleDateFormat`. Code outlook will look like bellow:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("contract-date-format");
Date date = formatter.parse(request.getParameter("strt_date"));
UtilDateTime.getTimestamp(date.getTime());
```